# How can I change a code from pointers to pointers to struct arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I have to change a 23000 lines code from pointers to pointers to struct arrays, the next code is an example, but if I solve the problem here that will be enough. 
I get the error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int'). If I write `int *content` that allows the code to run, but I have to write `int=content` and change the code `*((ptab->content)+pC1+17)`, I tried but I can't fix the error.

This is the example code in pointers to struct arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct box{
    int content;
};
struct box *ptab;

int pC1=5;

int main (){
    ptab=new struct box[64];

    if (*((ptab->content)+pC1+17)==0) {
        pC1=pC1+17;
    }
    cout<<pC1<<endl;
}
```

And this is the code in pointers, that already works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int *box;

int pC1=5;

int main (){
    box=new int[64];

    if (*(box+pC1+17)==0){
                                        pC1=pC1+17;
                                    }
    cout<<pC1<<endl;
}
```

Those are the examples, I would like to khow how to change from one code to the other, thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using "box[pC1+17]" type syntax for accessing array elements?

Comment: `change ... 23000 lines code` Are you sure you want to do that? Just because it's more beautiful or whatever?

Comment: Not at all, it's because the teacher wants that

Comment: If the rest of the code does not contain `struct box`, there might be a way to replace the implementation of the struct with a new class backed by a simple int array. You'd keep the `->content` syntax as is. But after it's compiled, it won't make a difference: the size of the struct is an int anyway, and ints align nicely - if not, there's `#pragma push(pack,1)` and `#pragma pop(pack)`.

Comment: I can't use box[pC1+17] because I have to know the box direction and after that change to another, in the real code I have many cases!

Comment: I can't use classes, because the requeriment don't allow that, thank you Kenney

Comment: `*((ptab->content)+pC1+17)` should be `(ptab+pc1+17)->content`, or more readably `ptab[pc1+17].content` . No star in either case.

Comment: "I can't use box[pC1+17]" - that comment makes no sense, it sounds like you are unaware that `box[pC1+17]` is exactly equivalent to `*(box+pC1+17)` except that it is easier to read

Comment: "I can't use classes" - all structs are classes in C++

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code remains essentially the same.  Pointer arithmetic works the same way regardless of the type.  It's just that when you have the address of a struct, you need to specify which member you want with `->`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct box{
    int content;
};
struct box *ptab;

int pC1=5;

int main (){
    ptab=new struct box[64];

    if ((ptab+pC1+17)->content==0) {  // you could also do (*(ptab+pC1+17)).content
        pC1=pC1+17;
    }
    cout<<pC1<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try that in the original code, thank you.

Comment: I would love to know what the this task was meant to accomplish.

Comment: The original code is a "automatic" game between two red horses and ten blue horses, in a chess board, red horses capture blue horses, and thats all.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom (working) code snippet, you're adding address offsets to an **int pointer** and dereferencing from that. That is, you're properly dereferencing a pointer.

In the top (nonfunctional) code snippet, you're adding address offsets to an **int** (not a pointer) and trying to dereference that, which isn't gonna work.

Comment: You can access a variable's address using `&`.

Comment: M.M's comment above, though, is on the money - a better solution than `&` is using bracket notation.